# Generate a screenshot from an html page on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to generate a screenshot from a html page on windows Azure.
This is the code I was using on my personal IIS and I know it works on every test machine.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new WebsiteToImage("http://www.google.com", "C:\\screenshot.jpg");
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    public class WebsiteToImage
    {
        internal string _url;
        internal string _fileName;

        public WebsiteToImage(string url, string fileName)
        {
            _url = url;
            _fileName = fileName;

            // Thread 
            var thread = new Thread(Generate);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
        }

        private void Generate()
        {
            using (var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false })
            {
                browser.Navigate(_url);
                browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

                browser.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Capture 
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(1280, 800))
            {
                var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
                browser.ClientSize = new Size(1280, 800);
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                browser.BringToFront();
                browser.DrawToBitmap(bmp, browser.Bounds);

                var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                bmp.Save(_fileName, ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)), encoderParameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on Azure I know I can't use GDI+ and I'm pretty sure I can't also use WebBrowser.
Any idea or alternative solution? Even third part component.

Comment: I wonder why you think you can't use GDI+ on Windows Azure? Are referring to `Azure Web Sites` or `Azure Cloud Services (a.k.a. Web Role)`? I am pretty sure you can use GDI+ on a Web Role!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Is there a webservice/API to grab a screenshot of another website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342611/is-there-a-webservice-api-to-grab-a-screenshot-of-another-website) and from there [this service](http://immediatenet.com/thumbnail_api.html) that do the task with an open source code. For the light use we're planning to do, this is better than a custom implemented solution.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said whether you're using Azure Web Sites or Azure Cloud Services, but from what you say about not being able to use GDI+, I'm guessing Web Sites?

You should certainly be able to run your code in a Cloud Service, either a Web or Worker role. If the code is part of a web application hosted on Web Sites, you can use an Azure Storage Queue to add the URL to be snap-shotted, then poll that queue on a worker role, run your code, and store the resulting file into Blob storage.

If your expected load on the screen-shot server is low, you could probably get away with an Extra-Small instance, which would cost very little.

Comment: I'll give the plus one, but I prefer a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update: [Awesomium should be an option](http://www.awesomium.com/) in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately this service has a quota and requires registration. We need to figure out if we can implement this on our server, first.

Comment: That service is for viewing a web page inside a console application.